# What command to use to make only our App working with MDM in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

My App is for kids, during school time my app only should work, rest of apps should not be enabled. Any command from server or it can be handled from iOS side?

Comment: No, iOS does not have this level of control available

Answer (score 1):

You can put your device in Kiosk-mode (when you can't exit some application). I am not sure whether it works for you.

There are several ways to do that

- Use AppLock configuration profile (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW35)

  I requires a device to be supervised.
- Install Restiction profile with autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs and use UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession API

  Look at this question:
  [autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs Key in Restrictions payload - iOS 7 MDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263805/autonomoussingleappmodepermittedappids-key-in-restrictions-payload-ios-7-mdm)